# Python & Matplotlib: Resampling plot, how to specify the ax to plot with

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the resampling result of a curve, something like this:

[image]

The problem is that I want to plot other curve as well, like this:

[image]

Now I can only get away with code like this:

```
import pandas as pd    
data = np.random.randn(100000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22,4))
for i in xrange(1,100):
    df_resampled = df.sample(frac=0.1, replace=True)
    ecdf = sm.distributions.ECDF(data)
    x = np.linspace(min(data), max(data))
    y_cdf = ecdf(x)

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1) 
    plt.plot(x, y_cdf, '-')

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2) 
    plt.plot(np.log(x), np.log(-np.log(1-y_cdf)),'-')
```

I'm wondering if I am doing it right, (the use of `ax1` and `ax2`). And if there are cleaner code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `sub_df.sample` comes from using `pandas`, but that is not stated. Please note that people cannot execute your code unless you provide some minimal data. Please check out  : [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Also the question is not that clear, it appears that you are repeating a calculation w/o need. You could just store all the samples:

```
samples=[]
for i in xrange(1,100):
    sub_df_resampled = sub_df.sample(frac=0.3, replace=True)  
    samples.append(sub_df_resampled)
```

and then reuse them.
Even then I'm not clear on how your plotting lines inside the for loops even use those samples.There is no indication that the items you are plotting are updated with the samples.

Comment: Just updated my code, seems like I've solved my problem. but you can still take a look.